# Why am I getting WebXml is not initialized yet?

Tags: jsf-2, weblogic, omnifaces

I´ve a Maven Web Application with JSF2, Primefaces, Spring, and Hibernate.
So I recently migrated my web application from Glassfish 3 to Weblogic 12c. 
When it run on Glassfish it worked fine but after migrating my application after some problems with the aspect libraries I managed to deploy it. But after running my application I found a bug. When my xhtml runs and loads data from my managed bean constructor it gets the data and renders it as expected, but if I fire an ajax event it gets the expected data but it doesn´t render the data and I get the next exception:

```
<11/01/2014 07:56:27 PM CST> <Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application> <BEA-000000> <Error Rendering View[/pages/dashboard.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebXml is not initialized yet. Please use #init(ServletContext) method to manually initialize it.
    at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.checkInitialized(WebXml.java:313)
    at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.getFormLoginPage(WebXml.java:294)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.startDocument(OmniPartialViewContext.java:253)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:287)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<11/01/2014 07:56:27 PM CST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@11936366[app:geotrack1-1.0-SNAPSHOT module:geotrack1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebXml is not initialized yet. Please use #init(ServletContext) method to manually initialize it.
    at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.checkInitialized(WebXml.java:313)
    at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.getFormLoginPage(WebXml.java:294)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.startDocument(OmniPartialViewContext.java:253)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:201)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<11/01/2014 07:56:27 PM CST> <Notice> <Diagnostics> <BEA-320068> <Watch "UncheckedException" in module "Module-FMWDFW" with severity "Notice" on server "AdminServer" has triggered at 11/01/2014 07:56:27 PM CST. Notification details: 
WatchRuleType: Log 
WatchRule: (SEVERITY = 'Error') AND ((MSGID = 'WL-101020') OR (MSGID = 'WL-101017') OR (MSGID = 'WL-000802') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-101020') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-101017') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-000802')) 
WatchData: DATE = 11/01/2014 07:56:27 PM CST SERVER = AdminServer MESSAGE = [ServletContext@11936366[app:geotrack1-1.0-SNAPSHOT module:geotrack1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception
```

Does anyone knows what´s happening??
Here is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <!-- Spring Context Configuration' s Path definition -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>         
    <!-- The Bootstrap listener to start up and shut down Spring's root WebApplicationContext. It is registered to Servlet Container -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- JSF Servlet is defined to container -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Mapping with servlet and url for the http requests. -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Configuracion de Quartz -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
    </listener>   

    <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>  

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            15
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

In my weblogic.xml I´ve:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <debug>true</debug>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <context-root>/geotrack1</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I hope someone knows what´s happening.
Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1):

It's already reported as [issue 273](https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=273) at 29 october 2013 and fixed for 1.7, which has *just* been released:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried the 1.7 version first but the repository did´nt found it.

Comment: Maven Central seems busy today. Give it some time to sync. If you can't wait, you can always grab `1.7-SNAPSHOT`. Sorry for trouble, if any.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it I change in my pom from omnifaces 1.6.3 to ominifaces 1.5